# Why my customized TreeNode does not scoll with my customized TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have customized `TreeNode` and `TreeView` because my `TreeView` has normal checkbox `TreeNode` and a customized `TreeNode` which contains a combobox. My treeview is scrollable but when I scroll down, the TreeNode with the combobox does not scroll with the treeview. Why?

Example :

[image: see the example]

`MyTreeNode` has `ComboBox` property:

```
 public ComboBox ComboBox
        {
            get
            {
                likelihood.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                return likelihood;
            }
            set
            {
                likelihood = value;
                likelihood.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            }
        }
```

and `MyTreeView` has this method:

```
protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {                
            if (e.Node is MyTreeNode)
            {
                myTreeNode = (MyTreeNode)e.Node;
                Controls.Add(myTreeNode.ComboBox);
                myTreeNode.ComboBox.SetBounds(myTreeNode.Bounds.X, myTreeNode.Bounds.Y, myTreeNode.Bounds.Width + 25, myTreeNode.Bounds.Height);   

                myTreeNode.ComboBox.Show();
            }
        }
```

`MyTreeView` is "registered" on two events (`AfterCheck` and `DrawNode`) and the property `DrawMode` is `OwnerDrawAll`.

Thank you

Comment: [A TreeView Control with ComboBox Dropdown Nodes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14544/A-TreeView-Control-with-ComboBox-Dropdown-Nodes).

Comment: @Jimi this article is the baseline of my code, but I still have issues.

Comment: This may be your reference code, but you made some mistakes in your implementation. That custom control doesn't show the behaviour you're describing, so the problem is in your code, but not the code your showing here. The modifications you added to the original project don't fit well, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. The TreeView knows nothing about the ComboBox and it won't synchronize its position while scrolling. You should do that synchronization manually.

In addition to calculating ComboBox bounds at the moment you display it, you should also reposition the ComboBox upon TreeView scroll events, and upon node expand/collapse events.

To handle expand/collapse, you should override [OnAfterExpand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.onafterexpand?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TreeView_OnAfterExpand_System_Windows_Forms_TreeViewEventArgs_) and [OnAfterCollapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.onaftercollapse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TreeView_OnAfterCollapse_System_Windows_Forms_TreeViewEventArgs_).

Handling scroll events is not a straightforward task because TreeView doesn't expose scroll events. Yet it's doable, here is an example from MSDN community Q&A: [treeview scrollbar event (detecting/controlling)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3ea9a4d3-0614-4d4f-a861-3cb30ca1bda0/treeview-scrollbar-event-detectingcontrolling?forum=winforms).

Comment: but how can I calculate bounds at the moment the MyTreeNode is diplayed?